# Why bash string array is not looping

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash


searchingelements=("<br/>","&npsp;")


for tags in "${searchingelements[@]}"
do
    echo -e "===========Searching for $tags==========\n"


done
```

prints

**===========Searching for `<br/>`,&npsp;==========**

Instead of

**===========Searching for `<br/>`==========**

**===========Searching for &npsp;==========**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

default array delimiter is space not comma, if you remove the comma it will work as intended.